# Scala: how to distinguish between an invoked function and a function parameter?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following code example in Scala:

```
def myfunc = {
   println("hello")
   10
}
val myParam = myfunc
```

When this code runs, myfunc is executed, meaning that the console will print "hello" and myfunc will return the value of 10.

Let's say that I want myParam to hold the function myfunc without invoking it. How can I do it?

Comment: try `myfunc(_)`?

Comment: This would work in case it would expect 1 argument, with no arguments it will fail

Comment: maybe `myfunc _`

Comment: @mck
myfunc(_) and myfunc _ work well both

Comment: This behaviour is a bit trickier than it looks at first. I wrote about it in detail [here](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/on-method-invocations-or-what-exactly-is-eta-expansion-1019b37e010c), if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala differentiates between methods and functions
With `def` you define a method and with `val` a function.
Functions can be assigned to a variable without Parentheses `myfunc` and are called with Parentheses `myfunc()`

There is a short conversion syntax to assign a method as a function to a variable

`mymethod(_)` //use as many underscores as arguments.

However it does not work for zero arguments.

For zero arguments the only option is

```
def mymethod = {
   println("hello")
   10
}
val myfunc = () => mymethod
```

See [How to use functions as variables (values) in Scala](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functions-as-variables-values-in-scala-fp) (but please note that the `m _`-syntax, mentioned in the blog post, [will be deprecated in the future](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/eta-expansion.html)).

Comment: Update: Sorry, my knowledge about the `m _`-syntax was slightly outdated. The `m _` syntax is indeed not future-proof. The blog post that you linked suggests to use the `mymethod _` syntax, which will soon be deprecated, I've added a remark on that. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Given there is a side-effect in `myFunc` method

```
def myfunc = {
   println("hello")    <== side-effect here
   10
}
```

tradition is to anyways hint at that with parenthesis `()`

```
def myfunc() = {
   println("hello")
   10
}
```

which has the added bonus of being less confusing regarding eta expansion.

Comment: This seems to introduce some orthogonal concern about the side-effects into the mix.
Assuming that `myfunc` had no side-effects, except being an expensive computation, then it would be declared without `()`-s. How would one convert it into a value then?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Wouldn’t expensive but nevertheless pure computation need to be evaluated only once, in which case perhaps lazy val definition would convey the idea better than nullary method?